# How to get JSON object from Facebook Post Insights

Tags: php, json, facebook

im trying to get value of impression from facebook post: but i cannot get a just a number from JSON and when i wanna specify field from json object i get error..

`<?php echo $reach['values']['value']; ?>`
this should return an **value** from insight call..

This is and **JSON** when i do i call from URL:
[image]

So then i try this:

```
<?php foreach ($post as $key): ?>
    <div class="postHolder">
        <h3><?php echo $key['message'] ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $key['id'] ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php 
        try {
            $imp_request = $fb->get('/'.$key['id'].'/insights/post_impressions_unique?fields=values');
            $reach = $imp_request->getGraphEdge();
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            // When Graph returns an error
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
            echo "<script>window.top.location.href='http://localhost/insights/'</script>";
            exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

                    ?>
        <div class="insHolder">
            <?php echo $reach; ?>
        </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and this returns me:

`[{"values":[{"value":1}],"id":"{post_id}\/insights\/post_impressions_unique\/lifetime"}]`

Comment: You need to decode the json into an array -> `$reach = json_decode($reach, true);`..

Comment: I try that also.. But i dont know how to specify the value object in the array..

Comment: Decode it, then get it from `echo $reach['data']['values']['value']`.

Comment: Getting an error `Notice: Array to string conversion`

Comment: Can you do `print_r($reach['data']['values']['value']);` and show me what it gives you

Comment: [Getting this error.. its img](http://imageshack.com/a/img921/518/xTbrtU.jpg)

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: data in ...`

Comment: I used this: `<?php echo json_encode($reach[0]['values']); ?>`
And im pretty close for the number but still im getting:
`[{"value":1}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

I used this code for get the closest object: **`[{'value'=1}]`**

- `<?php echo json_encode($reach[0]['values']); ?>`

Then i used basic **JS** call to remove all character whats are not **[0-9]**

```
function reachText() {
    $('.reach').each(function(){
        reach = $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        $(this).text(reach);
    });
}
```